# Can python xlrd read in raw data instead of unicode data?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

Can python xlrd read in raw data instead of unicode data? I tried to use python xlrd to read in an excel file. But I can only get the unicode string instead of the raw string from the file. How to get raw strings from the excel file using xlrd? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the encoding of the existing data, you can go ahead with encoding the data *after* it is read by xlrd.

`data = u'This is sample read by xlrd'
r_data = data.encode('utf-8')`

Suggested reading:

1. [Effbot - Converting Unicode to 8 bit strings](http://effbot.org/zone/unicode-convert.htm)
2. [Joel On Software - Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)